# como hacer una seguida de numeros en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

en una base datos tengo el siguiente problema:

```
ID  premio ordenar precio Fecha       escala_Vencida
1   1      1       1000   30-12-2016  si
2   1      2       2000   30-12-2016  si
3   1      3       3000   30-12-2016  si
4   2      4       4000   30-12-2016  si
5   2      5       5000   30-12-2016  si
6   2      6       6000   30-12-2016  si
7   3      1       6000   30-1-2017   no
8   3      2       4000   30-1-2017   no
9   3      3       5000   30-1-2017   no
10  4      4       1000   30-1-2017   no
11  4      5       2000   30-1-2017   no
12  4      6       3000   30-1-2017   no
```

Necesito hacer que premio esta ordenada el problema es la culumna (Ordenar) necesito que se haga de numero menor a mayor desde 1 hasta infinito siempre que la escala no este vencia es decir esta marque (NO) y el precio sea de menor a mayor, dicho en este caso el numero 6 representan 2 premios distintos, en el caso de el primer premio el orden esta BIEN (desde el ID 1 al 6) pero el segundo esta desordenado (desde el ID 7 al 12) el segundo premio necesito insertarlo de manera ordenada mediante un insert de MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
(
premio,
ordenar,
precio,
fecha,
escala_vencida,
)
VALUES
(
premio,
ordenar,<--- problema al ordenar
precio,
fecha,
escala_vencida,
)
```

IMPORTANTE el ID es UNICO no se repite en toda la Tabla.

Obviamente esto deberia hacerce desde un SELECT e detalle es que no se como ordenarlo a partir de lo que mencione arriba.

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que estas en Stack Overflow, el cual a diferencia de sitios como Yahoo Respuestas, no es un sitio donde preguntes algo y esperes ayuda sin siquiera mostrar algo de codigo, algo de esfuerzo, para asi poder ayudarte, muestranos que has hecho, que errores tienes durante el proceso, muestranos el codigo, para asi poder ayudarte efectivamente.

Comment: La pregunta es difícil de entender. Aparte, si tienes problemas al ordenar deberías compartir la `SELECT` y no el `INSERT`

Comment: Amigo Ivan Botero obviamente si yo tuviera la idea NO hubiera preguntado por aquí , ni me hubiera molestado en hacer un post yo hay coloque la idea de mi pregunta el amigo Alvaro mas o menos me entendió se que es a partir de un select pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: La tabla original tiene esos valores guardados? si es así los campos todos son integer (premio, ordenar, precio)? y supongo que el ID lo creas al listar.

Answer (score 0):

En otras bases de datos existe la clausula OVER que determina una partición o rango de valores, sobre los que aplicar una función de ventana, o una función de agregado.

Por ejemplo: Numera los registros, creando una partición por escalaVencida, ordenado por precio. O sea, va numerando mientras no cambia la escalaVencida.

> ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY escalaVencida ORDER BY precio)

En MySql no existe está funcion y debe realizarse usando variables. La ventaja es que las variables se pueden inicializar en la misma sentencia SQL.

```
select 
       @ordenar := @ordenar + 1 as ordenar,
       ID, premio, precio, Fecha, escala_vencida
from
    (select @ordenar := 0) i,
    (select ID, premio, precio, Fecha, escala_Vencida 
     from premios 
     where escala_Vencida = 'no' 
     order by precio) t;


+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| ordenar | ID | premio | precio |        Fecha        | escala_vencida |
+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|    1    | 10 |    4   |  1000  | 30.01.2017 00:00:00 |       no       |
+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|    2    | 11 |    4   |  2000  | 30.01.2017 00:00:00 |       no       |
+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|    3    | 12 |    4   |  3000  | 30.01.2017 00:00:00 |       no       |
+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|    4    |  8 |    3   |  4000  | 30.01.2017 00:00:00 |       no       |
+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|    5    |  9 |    3   |  5000  | 30.01.2017 00:00:00 |       no       |
+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|    6    |  7 |    3   |  6000  | 30.01.2017 00:00:00 |       no       |
+---------+----+--------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Puedes probar aquí: http://rextester.com/QWJG61661